# Josh Smith's MVVM Demo App: Add commands to MainWindowViewModel's command list

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, command, demo

I have a question concerning [Josh Smith's famous demo app on MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

I try building a "real" application around it to learn WPF.

He creates this CommandsList in the MainWindowViewModel containing 2 Commands (create new and view all customers). This list is readonly (why? any particular reason?).
I thougt it would be nice to add and remove some commands, depending on the workspace that is currently selected. Like edit or delete a customer when it has the focus and so on.

How would I accomplish this?! Can I just make it a normal list and add commands? Or bind the Commands-View to a commands list of the selected workspace instead of the MainWindow? How? Any other ways? Please share your ideas!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write an article about [defining the commands in the viewmodel](http://blog.notifychanged.com/2008/07/28/defining-commandbindings-in-the-viewmodel/) and how you can then use all the possibilities of databinding to show your commands.

One of the possibilities mentioned was to

> define a filtered version of the
>   command list “local menu commands” for
>   direct use in the view

Something similar is what I think you should do in your situation: write some filtered version of the command list and change it depending on your state.

The article also contains a link to a very simple demo application that shows only how this works so I think it could help you.

Comment: Your article seems very detailed and interesting. I will work through it and share my experiences here. Thank you.

Comment: after long considerations, I will use <a href="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx">Josh Smith's approach</a>, because I find it, no offense, easier to understand (this means nothing though, cuz I am pretty a noob).

Since you mention it in your article, I set your answer as the accepted answer =) Thank you very much.

Comment: maybe, the article you mention of Josh Smith is easier to understand because it is closer to the "original" concept of the commands in wpf.
The commands in the viewmodel is a construction made on top of that, i maybe everything gets clearer to you if first you read some explanation about the neat wpf commands, for example here:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands
(and, of course, there is no offense at all)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://fknet.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/porting-a-wpf-app-with-mvvm-design-pattern-to-silverlight-4-using-caliburn-fluentvalidation/

I use messages via Caliburn.